# Tor Browser Bundle on Mac - how to run obfsproxy?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, pluggable-transports, obfsproxy

I have downloaded and installed the Tor browser bundle v. 3.6.3 for Mac
Website says Obfsproxy is standard included in that one - which is correct- it works in Tor Browser.

But I need to run it independently for use with OpenVPN.
On Windows this is really easy to run it from the TBB, it's just a matter of running the obfsproxy.exe from the Pluggable Transports folder with the necessary parameters.

But I simply cannot seem to find an executable file called obfsproxy anywhere inside the Tor Browser application package.
I am following for example this guide - [link](https://www.ivpn.net/knowledgebase/142/Tunnelblick---I-canandsharp039t-connect-from-China-or-Vietnam-or-Iran-etc.html) - which says it should be inside the package folder Contents/MacOS but it's not there.

How can I run obfsproxy separately from the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$ cd TorBrowser.app/Tor/PluggableTransports
$ ./obfsproxy.bin
```

Comment: How could I have missed that - I guess that is what happens when blind staring on another folder. I found the .bin now. I am not 100% there yet though. When i run it, I get this error: 'from Crypto.Cipher import _AES
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Tor/PluggableTransports/Crypto/Cipher/_AES.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Applications/TorBrowser.app/Tor/PluggableTransports/Crypto/Cipher/_AES.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture' - any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your AES encryption library is either 32-bit on a 64-bit system or vice versa. Find out your correct architecture and re-install the Tor browser for that architecture.